# How to get value of lat and lgn with Marker Animations

Tags: get, marker

I need get value of geolocalization (lat/lng) when drag my marker or when click in marker and after display in input field.

My cod:

```
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: {lat: -22.778825, lng: -45.167888}
          });
          marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
            function toggleBounce() {

                if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
                    marker.setAnimation(null);
                } else {
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                }
          }
```